# Upgrade to 12.10 fails with grub fatal error

Tags: installation, server, upgrade, 12.10, lvm

After upgrading to server 12.10 grub is complaining, and thus no boot. 
Boot-repair and all other solution fail because for some reason grub-install can not read /boot/grub from my lvm system disk. 
I have also tried to reinstall from scratch reusing only my /home dir but the result is the same.

Surely this ain't right...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the same applies to me :-)

this is because of the new grub version, which is a bit taller and cannot find enough space. best is to keep 12.04 and not to move, or move without using the new grub version. Moving lvm is quite dangerous and time consuming, don't do that.

for next time try not to allocate the entire disk to lvm...

Answer (score 0):

Meanwhile in Ubuntu land....

it appears that grub-pc on 12.10 server uses a core.img to embed in the mbr which is slightly bigger than 12.04. As a result the exiting img canot be replaced unless users manage to 'move' the entire partioning system a little to make extra room. This however is not as straight forward as it seems especially for users that have their entire disk allocated to lvm or the likes. Re-installing 12.04 and reusing the existing lvm probably is by far the easiest solution.